# Draw horizontal lines (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to run the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, color="g") 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
hlines=[40,50]
ax.hlines(hlines, 1, len(x), color='g')
plt.show()
```

I expect it to draw something like this:
[image]
Drawing chart is not a problem, it works, but drawing horizontal lines doesn't work.

When I run my code it draws:

[image]

P.S. x created this way: dates to matplotlib dates

```
x.append(matplotlib.dates.date2num(datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are drawing a horizontal line from x-axis=`1` to x-axis=`len(x)`, which are just arbitrary integers that does not represent anything on your graph: your x-axis is much larger because you use `matplotlib.dates.date2num`. You need to properly assign the range for your horizontal line. For example:

```
ax.hlines(hlines, min(x), max(x), color='g')
```

or

```
ax.hlines(hlines,
          matplotlib.dates.date2num(datetime.strptime(mindate, '%Y%m%d')),
          matplotlib.dates.date2num(datetime.strptime(maxdate, '%Y%m%d')),
          color='g')
```

or you could just use `axhline`:

```
ax.axhline(40, color='g')
ax.axhline(50, color='g')
```